# How to make the bot send out multiple messages in sequence over REST API? [Rasa]

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have a conversation where the bot send out multiple replies.
For example:
User: “Hi”
Bot: “Hello”
Bot: “How can I help you?”

Here the bot sends out multiple messages. In interactive mode this is working fine. However, after I setup the REST API (following this How to serve chatbot from server?), the bot does not send out multiple messages for obvious reasons. How can I get this working?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: When the user sends a message. I have the bot utter multiple utterances. That is the story. However, I've made a webhook and connected it via REST API

Answer (score 0):

you can use `\n\n` inside a text response to split it into two messages..

Unfortunately it does not work with button response messages.
Here You can use custom actions with as many `dispatcher.utter_message()` events as you want..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

actually its pretty easy. Just do something like this in your stories or in your rules:

```
- story: requesting web development info
  steps:
    - intent: request_web_developement_info
    - action: utter_web_developement_info
    - action: utter_request_meeting
```

remember to define your utters correctly and make tests